# How to update runtime values in the sense to voting as a refrence

Tags: php, ajax

Just like SO, What kind of logic have to build for creating this, I know using `ajax` it's working, but how ?

Ex. first user have vote up of second one and at same time second user can see he/she get vote up/down

Comment: You should probably look for web sockets or ajax polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Explanation on Following Site.

http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery